# How can I click this button via selenium, it always says list object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click the "show more results" button in google image search via selenium.

The page is https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=circle&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifxd-wqr_VAhXEopQKHQpSB_AQ_AUICigB&biw=1249&bih=927

The page should be scroll down 4 times so that you can see the button.

the html code is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fByRX.jpg)

my code is below

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class ImgCrawler:
    def __init__(self,searchlink = None):
        self.link = searchlink
        self.soupheader = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3176.2 Safari/537.36"}
        self.scrolldown = None
        self.jsdriver = None

    def getChromeCanary(self):
        self.jsdriver = webdriver.Chrome("f:\software\python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
        self.jsdriver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.jsdriver.get(self.link)

    def scrollDownUseChromeCanary(self, scrolltimes = 1, sleeptime = 10):
        for i in range(scrolltimes):
            self.jsdriver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
            time.sleep(sleeptime)

    def clickNextPage(self):
        return self.jsdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input.ksb._kvc").click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    weblink = "https://www.google.com.hk/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1461&bih=950&q=circle&oq=circle&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1497.3829.0.4548.10.9.1.0.0.0.185.1136.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.img..2.7.974...0i10k1.4YZkQiWXzGo"
    img = ImgCrawler(weblink)
    img.getChromeCanary()
    img.scrollDownUseChromeCanary(4,5)
    img.clickNextPage()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to point the first element of your query :

```
self.jsdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input.ksb._kvc")[0].click()
```

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

> To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):

Comment: why? There is only one button.

Comment: `find_elements_by_css_selector` always returns a list of all matching elements, for one or hundred, even 0 will give an empty list

Comment: Though ,you are right, thank you! It works.  But I don't understand. I search the web page source code. There is the only one place that match "input.ksb._kvc". Why it returns a lot?

Comment: maybe there's only one, you can check the results with `print(len(self.jsdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input.ksb._kvc")))`

Comment: I try. The length is 1

Comment: But the type is list

Comment: @LouiLin think about this function has to return a convenient object as result, it will be painful to guess what kind of object it is depending on the context for 0,1 or 1000 results. The best way to handle that is to return a container like a list

Answer (score 1):

`find_elements_...()` methods usually used

- to get list of `WebElements` for following iteration through it:

  ```
  [element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
  ```
- to locate element by index if there is no unique identifier:

  ```
  driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class_name')[1]
  ```

In other cases you can simply use `find_element_...()` methods that returns single `WebElement`

Try to replace

```
self.jsdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input.ksb._kvc").click()
```

with

```
self.jsdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ksb._kvc").click()
```